# How do I take the response from one JMeter rest sampler and use it as input to another?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test that has a rest sampler that outputs a value as such in the response data:

{"Var1":"xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"}

I need to take that out put (Var1) and use it as input for the next rest sampler in the following test step. I have a line in a BeanShell pre-processor that says:

String clearText = "somestring1" + "_" + var1 + ":" + "somestring2";

where var1 is derived from a Regular Expression Extractor from the preceding RestSampler (that is how I got the out put {"Var1":"xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"} ).

Problem: I get a void for var1 in the output of the second rest sampler.

What am i doing wrong? how can i get the value from the output of the first rest sampler and use it as input in the second rest sampler??

Thanks.

ironmantis7x

Comment: Check jmeter logs for any error. Use debug sampler to see what are your other variables. Provide your test plan and logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that your Regular Expression Extractor is correctly obtaining `Var1`? If you're testing RESTful API it's better to use [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/) (you will need *Extras with Libs Set*).

Configure JSON Path Extractor as follows:

- Reference Name: `Var1` or whatever you like
- JSON Path: `$.Var1` this one assumes your response.

So you would be able to provide the variable value as `${Var1}` or `${__V(Var1)}` to 2nd request.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (Scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for more details on how to properly install the extension and build up JSON Path queries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your API returns response in JSON format then use below solution :

**#1 To use this parameter within same thread group:-**
a] Right click on Thread Name --> click on "Add" --> click on "Post Processors"  -->  select "Json Extractor"

b] On 'Json Extractor" window, select below values :
Variable Names == test                //give any variable name(user-defined)
JSON Path expressions == $.[0].name   //this will pick value of "name" param from API's Json response

c] Now to use ${test} to pass this value to other API as input. By using ${test} you can use it anywhere.

**#2 To use this ${test} parameter in other thread group :-**
a] Right click on Thread Name --> click on "Add" --> click on "Post Processors"  -->  select "Json Extractor"

b] On 'Json Extractor" window, select below values :
Variable Names == test                //give any variable name(user-defined)
JSON Path expressions == $.[0].name   //this will pick value of "name" param from API's Json response

c] Right click on First Thread Name(where variable value is populated) --> click on "Add" --> click on "Assertions"  -->  select "BeanShell Assertions"

d] Under "script" section paste below code :
${__setProperty(test, ${test})};

e] Now you can access this first API's response value using ${__property(test)}
variable